# Mapfish 3 merge datasource with multiple maps

Tags: mapfish, mapfish-print

I would like to combine the examples of [merging datasources](https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print/blob/master/examples/src/test/resources/examples/merged_datasource/config.yaml) and having [multiple maps](https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print/tree/master/examples/src/test/resources/examples/multiple_maps).

So instead of having a table datasource (1st example) I have a map datasource like the second example.

The goal is to output a report with a map in the first page, and other maps with features in the following pages (from datasource).

How to accomplish that? (config.yaml)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using only one report, with 2 createmap processors

config.yaml

```
templates:
  report: !template
    reportTemplate: report.jrxml
    outputFilename: report-${yyyyMMdd_hhmmss}
    attributes:
      ...
      map: !map
        maxDpi: 400
        width: 499
        height: 657
        ...
      datasource: !datasource
        attributes:
          ...
          map2: !map
            maxDpi: 254
            width: 220
            height: 332
            ...
      scalebar: !scalebar
        width: 126
        height: 47
      northArrow: !northArrow
        size: 50
        default:
          graphic: "images/north.svg"
    processors:
    - !reportBuilder # compile all reports in current directory
      directory: '.'
    - !createMap {}
    - !createScalebar {}
    - !createNorthArrow {}
    - !createDataSource
      processors:
        - !createMap
          inputMapper:
            map2: map
    tableData: jrDataSource
```

In report.jrxml

```
...
<parameter name="mapSubReport" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="mapSubReport" class="java.lang.String"/>
...
```